# Buggy incompatibility with java.net.URLEncoder vs. java.net.URI and java.io.File?

Tags: java, url, uri, urlencode

I just discovered some bug in java related to URL encoding, involving the java.net.URLEncoder, java.net.URI, and java.io.File, independently or together all depending on the same underlying thing.

The issue is the treatment of the "+" in URL encoding. Many people, including the authors of java.net.URLEncoder, believe that in an encoded string a `+` stands for a space and is equivalent to `%20`. Here are the rules as per java.net.URLEncoder

When encoding a String, the following rules apply:

- The alphanumeric characters "a" through "z", "A" through "Z" and "0" through "9" remain the same.
- The special characters ".", "-", "*", and "_" remain the same.
- The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".
- All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into [percent-encoding]

When I read in RFC 1738 and RFC 3986 on URLs and URIs respectively, I find that the use of "+" to encode space is not actually recognized there. This took me by surprise.

Here is a program that shows something is wrong. But it is not quite clear who is at fault.

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("1. " +                               URLEncoder.encode("name with+space"));
        System.out.println("2. " +          new URI("file:/tmp/"+URLEncoder.encode("name with+space")));
        System.out.println("3. " + new File(new URI("file:/tmp/"+URLEncoder.encode("name with+space"))));
        System.out.println("4. " + new URI("file:/tmp/"+URLEncoder.encode("name with+space")).getPath());
        System.out.println("5. " + new File(new URI("file:/tmp/name%20with%2Bspace")));
        System.out.println("6. " + new File(new URI("file:/tmp/name%20with%2Bspace")).toURI());
        System.out.println("7. " + new URI("file", "", "/tmp/name with+space", "name with+space", null));
    }
}
```

this outputs:

```
1. name+with%2Bspace
2. file:/tmp/name+with%2Bspace
3. \tmp\name+with+space
4. /tmp/name+with+space
5. \tmp\name with+space
6. file:/C:/tmp/name%20with+space
7. file:///tmp/name%20with+space?name%20with+space
```

To explain,

1. URL encoded "name with+space" is "name+with%2Bspace" -- that is correct by the URLEncoder's own specification, but then the use of + to encode space is of questionable authority.
2. URI from URL encoded "name with+space" is "name+with%2Bspace", URI did not choke on the + but it accepts it as is.
3. when turning the URI of the last step into a file, we get "name+with+space", that is, the first "+" which supposedly had encoded the space, is now a literal "+"
4. when getting the path component of the URI the + is not interpreted as escaped space
5. but when the "+" is turned into a percent encoding "$20" things work properly.
6. When the file is then turned back to a URI, File and URI together think that "+" need not be escaped to "%2B".
7. Finally since URI promises to take care of encoding when the multi-argument constructor is used, I want to see if it correctly encoded URL encoded query parameters, since those are considered to be the purpose of the URLEncoder class (form URL-encoding), but again, no escaping of the "+" showing no understanding that "+" is short for "%20".

My analysis is that URLEncoder is operating under some non-authoritative yet very customary rules under which the "+" is encoding for space, synonymous to "%20", and a real "+" should be escaped to "%2B". Perhaps there is the form encoding that is based off URL encoding but actually isn't.

The java.net.URI simply does not agree with URLEncoder. It accepts "%2B" for "+" but does not produce it. And it does not understand a "+" as short hand for "%20". This does not even appear to be a subtle difference between URL and URI, but I see nowhere that "+" is specified as encoding space.

This is a pit-fall pit, internally conflicting specifications used by Java and they cannot work together. There also seems to be no "right way" to do this, because there is no URIEncoder function that works correctly to combine with URL, or is there?

Answer (score 2):

You're misinterpreting the use-case for [`java.net.URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html) by incorrectly assuming - from its name - that it encodes URLs. It does not, so you're comparing apples with oranges. Its purpose is (quoted from the javadoc):

> This class contains static methods for converting a String to the
> `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME format.

So, its purpose is not to encode URLs, but to encode names/values for form bodies posted with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Historically, it has also been (mis)used to encode names/values in the search-part of a query, but that is not correct.

As far as I know, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is not defined in an RFC, but it is only defined in the HTML specification (the javadoc of `URLEncoder` specifically links to the HTML 4 specification). The HTML specification defines the encoding of <space> as `+` and then the encoding specified in RFC 1738 (it doesn't explicitly define `+` as `%2b`, but this is implicitly expected, otherwise it would not be possible to discern between space and actual +), see the [HTML 4 specification section application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1):

> This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content
> type must be encoded as follows:
>
> 1. Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in
>    [[RFC1738]](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/references.html#ref-RFC1738), section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are
>    replaced by `%HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits
>    representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are
>    represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A').
> 2. The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by `=' and name/value
>    pairs are separated from each other by `&'.

In short, this is not a bug, and you should not use `URLEncoder` to encode (or `URLDecoder` to decode) parts of a URL, because that is not what it's for.

Comment: Yes, it is surely a confusion between specs. But it is not correct to "blame" this on me "misunderstanding" anything. The confusion exists, and my test about URI encoding the query part not using the + for %20 shows that. The real question is: what *should* one do to do these things safely and correctly?

Comment: @GuntherSchadow You seem to think `URLEncoder` is for encoding URLs, but it is not (despite its name suggesting otherwise), it is an encoder to generate names/values that are encoded for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So to me it seems your problem derives from you not understanding the purposes of `URLEncoder`.